# Make Python stop emitting a carriage return when writing newlines to sys.stdout

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm on Windows and Python is (very effectively) preventing me from sending a stand-alone `'\n'` character to STDOUT. For example, the following will output `foo\r\nvar`:

```
sys.stdout.write("foo\nvar")
```

How can I turn this "feature" off?  Writing to a file first is not an option, because the output is being piped.

Comment: What code are you currently using?

Comment: Whatever sys.stdout is opened with.

Comment: I meant what are you using to write to it? `print`? `sys.stdout.write()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following before writing anything:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
   import os, msvcrt
   msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

If you only want to change to binary mode temporarily, you can write yourself a wrapper:

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def binary_mode(f):
   if sys.platform != "win32":
      yield; return

   import msvcrt, os
   def setmode(mode):
      f.flush()
      msvcrt.setmode(f.fileno(), mode)

   setmode(os.O_BINARY)
   try:
      yield
   finally:
      setmode(os.O_TEXT)

with binary_mode(sys.stdout), binary_mode(sys.stderr):
   # code
```

Comment: @John: 4 seconds difference :D Guess we both used the same search terms ;)

Comment: "this was the result of a very quick Google search", only after I phrased the question in such a way as to make the searching easier.  I had spent about an hour looking for "make python stop emiting carriage return", and so I came here.

Comment: @John: Oh, that wasn't meant as an offense, sorry. I've also spent hours researching something, only to finally be pointed to a link which must have been among the first 10 results for *some* of my queries, but which I just happened to not click at. Sometimes it's a matter of luck :) Have fun!

Answer (score -4):

[Add 'r' before the string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals):

```
sys.stdout.write(r"foo\nvar")
```

As expected, it also works for print.

Comment: Ahm, it will print the backslash and the n literally?