# Write/print newline to sys.stdout without a carriage return under Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, carriage-return

How do you write a newline(`\n`)-terminated line to stdout under Windows without it being prefixed with a carriage return (`\r`)?

For instance, both the following write the 6 characters "line\r\n" to file.txt

```
python -c "print('line\n', end='')" >file.txt
python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('line\n')" >file.txt
```

Is there not a way to write the 5 characters "line\n" ???

Use of msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY) as per [Make Python stop emitting a carriage return when writing newlines to sys.stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020325/make-python-stop-emitting-a-carriage-return-when-writing-newlines-to-sys-stdout) doesn't seem to work.

I am using 3.4.4 under Windows 10

Comment: just tested, it works with Python 2.7, but you're right, with python 3.4 the carriage return is issued.