# Git - fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards

Tags: git, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate a CVS repo to Git using cvs2git.
Unfortunately my cvs repo has many branches with regex.
While doing git fast import(unix) it reports the error below

```
fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: refs/tags/Release21_3_4_0_0_3_7_10[3_8_4_3]
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_27083
```

I tried to delete these tags, but no luck. i think it is taking the entire history.
I am not able to import the HEAD alone also.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: You could try this out, if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10020482/26396

Answer (score 4):

You can find out more [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html). This is how git verify that your branch name is a valid name.

The problem is the [] characters.
Try to locally create branch with those names and you will see the error.

[Here](http://tiku.io/questions/1724676/when-using-cvs2svn-how-can-you-rename-symbols-such-that-a-branch-and-tag-resolve) is a  detailed post(s) abot what and how to do it.

[image: Git try to create branch with the given name]

You must rename the tags in order to get them into git.